# Xamarin Forms, using WCF Service Error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently I have Xamarin.Forms application which use service reference WCF, SellerCloud API which is on "http://ws.timezone123.com/SCService.asmx".

Referencing SCService I receive two compile exceptions
"The type or namespace name 'XmlElement' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Xml' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" and "The type or namespace name 'schema' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

http://prntscr.com/g5sgf1

Currently library, from which I am trying to reference service is Portal Class Library with Target Framework "Profile7".

Can you suggest what I can do in that case to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: (Sorry for the poor english) I did not like the results I get implementing the web service references at the portable project. There's a lot of work more to make it working and I got rid of it. Instead of it, I used dependency injection and specific platform implementations.

Comment: Use Profile78 and it will work like a charm. Also Connected Services is not the same as WCF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you add the service reference to PCL?

You are trying to consume ASMX web service( XML web service with SOAP protocol). As i can see your screenshot ,you added a connected service (typically used for azure app services) not a **Web reference**. In order to consume ASMX service you need to add a **Web reference**.

Problem is, web reference is not available in PCL .But it is available in platform specific projects(right click the droid or Ios project --->Add--->Web Reference).

If you add web reference correctly it will generate proxies within your platform specif projects.Then you need to access generated web methods through **Dependency service** in your PCL.Please check following documentation for further idea

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/#asmx

Following question is some what similar to your problem

[Is there any supported way to call asmx web services from cross-platform Xamarin code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699766/is-there-any-supported-way-to-call-asmx-web-services-from-cross-platform-xamarin)